# Backup advanced phone settings

Tags: backup

I couldn't find a similar thread

I use Titanium Backup to backup apps and their internal settings, but there are so many things it fails to, like:

- Accessibility settings
- Apps and their permissions
- Custom notification sounds for every contact
- Notification settings for every app (silent/loud, show up/don't)
- Bluetooth pairings (**important: with their respective pins**)
- Search settings
- Special app access
- Battery optimization
- Device admin apps
- Display over other apps
- Do Not Disturb access
- Modify system settings
- Notification access
- Picture-in-picture
- Unrestricted data
- Install unknown apps
- Usage access

Is there a way to do so ?

I have Tasker, if it helps, but no idea how to make such an advanced thing.

Side question: is any of these settings store on a text file ?

A system image/clone is not a good option, as it clones all the other garbage from the phone with it. All that is needed are those settings above

Android 9
Rooted and everything